# Image animation issues codename one

Tags: java, codenameone

want to animate my logo by zooming it to an splash screen.
tried the following so far:

```
@Override
protected void postSpash1(Form f) {
    findLogoLabel(f).setPreferredW(findLogoLabel(f).getPreferredW() * 5);
    findAnimateContainer(f).animateLayoutAndWait(2000);
    findLogoLabel(f).setPreferredSize(null);
}
```

The image doesn't animate and enlarges itself. However it changes its size abruptly after 2 sec which is not what I'm looking for. I want the zooming effect(the img should grow bigger slowly to a certain extent)

I tried other ways too, but the label moves from up to down smoothly instead of bg img getting bigger

```
findLogoLabel(f).setPreferredH(findLogoLabel(f).getPreferredH() * 3);
findAnimateContainer(f).animateLayoutAndWait(2000);
findLogoLabel(f).setPreferredSize(null);
```

**PS:** I set the bg image in logoLabel (Label) , Animatecontainer is the container that contains logoLabel.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking API's are somewhat tricky as they might collide with some other behaviors preventing the rest of the current dispatch thread from finishing its job.

Also you set the null after animating instead of before...

So in your case this should work (with old Java 5 syntax):

```
@Override
protected void postSpash1(final Form f) {
    findLogoLabel(f).setPreferredW(findLogoLabel(f).getPreferredW() * 5);
    Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          findLogoLabel(f).setPreferredSize(null);
          findAnimateContainer(f).animateLayoutAndWait(2000);
        }
    });
}
```

With cool Java 8 lambdas:

```
@Override
protected void postSpash1(final Form f) {
    findLogoLabel(f).setPreferredW(findLogoLabel(f).getPreferredW() * 5);
    Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
       findLogoLabel(f).setPreferredSize(null);
       findAnimateContainer(f).animateLayoutAndWait(2000);
    });
}
```